# using the output of paste() as an object, within a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, model, build-automation, paste

I want to construct a matrix of results for 48 GLMs (including model coefficients, R2, etc.). I though in calling the model objects by using a `for` loop which iteratively call them using `paste()` and `mget()` functions, which create a variable with the same name that the model object. Imagine these are the model objects:

```
var1_ds1_1<-glm(var1~var_ds1)
var1_ds2_1<-glm(var1~var_ds2)
var1_ds3_1<-glm(var1~var_ds3)
```

My problem arise when I create a name to call the object using `paste()` and `mget()` to automatically create an object name identical to the model object name (in this simple example `mget(paste ("var1",table.row))` should result in `var1_ds1_1`, but I cannot extract the model coefficients or any other parameters.

```
for (tab.row in 1:48) {
     result.matrix[tab.row,]<-mget(paste ("var1_ds",table.row,"_1"))$coef[1] # An example to extract the linear coefficient
}
```

My question is: How can I automatically generate the names of the model objects to store their parameters into a new result matrix?

The new matrix should be:

```
Row Variable Dataset Slope P-Value R2
 1  Var 1    1       1.3   0.001   50%
 2  Var 1    2       0.8   0.004   32%   
 .    .      .        .      .      .
48  Var n    n        .      .      .
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't have an `r` tag, so most R folks will have missed this.

Comment: Have you tried `get` instead of `mget` and `paste0` instead of `paste`? Better still, rather than creating a long list of variables, when you fit the 48 models you could collect of the results in a list.