# performing a calculation with a `paste`d vector reference

Tags: r, for-loop, automation, paste

So I have some lidar data that I want to calculate some metrics for (I'll attach a link to the data in a comment).
I also have ground plots that I have extracted the lidar points around, so that I have a couple hundred points per plot (19 plots). Each point has X, Y, Z, height above ground, and the associated plot.

I need to calculate a bunch of metrics on the plot level, so I created `plotsgrouped` with `split(plotpts, plotpts$AssocPlot)`.
So now I have a data frame with a "page" for each plot, so I can calculate all my metrics by the "plot page". This works just dandy for individual plots, but I want to automate it. (yes, I know there's only 19 plots, but it's the principle of it, darn it! :-P)
So far, I've got a for loop going that calculates the metrics and puts the results in a data frame called `Results`. I pulled the names of the groups into a list called `groups` as well.

```
for(i in 1:length(groups)){
Results$Plot[i] <- groups[i]
Results$Mean[i] <- mean(plotsgrouped$PLT01$Z)
Results$Std.Dev.[i] <- sd(plotsgrouped$PLT01$Z)
Results$Max[i] <- max(plotsgrouped$PLT01$Z)
Results$75%Avg.[i] <- mean(plotsgrouped$PLT01$Z[plotsgrouped$PLT01$Z <= quantile(plotsgrouped$PLT01$Z, .75)])
Results$50%Avg.[i] <- mean(plotsgrouped$PLT01$Z[plotsgrouped$PLT01$Z <= quantile(plotsgrouped$PLT01$Z, .50)])
...
and so on.
```

The problem arises when I try to do something like:
`Results$mean[i] <- mean(paste("plotsgrouped", groups[i],"Z", sep="$"))`. `mean()` doesn't recognize the `paste` as a reference to the vector `plotsgrouped$PLT27$Z`, and instead fails. I've deduced that it's because it sees the quotes and thinks, "Oh, you're just some text, I can't get the mean of you." or something to that effect.
Btw, groups is a list of the 19 plot names: PLT01-PLT27 (non-consecutive sometimes) and FTWR, so I can't simply put a sequence for the numeric part of the name.
**Anyone have an easier way to iterate across my test plots and get arbitrary metrics?

I feel like I have all the right pieces, but just don't know how they go together to give me what I want.**
Also, if anyone can come up with a better title for the question, feel free to post it or change it or whatever.

Comment: sounds like a job for the `plyr` package, but it would be easier to discuss on a minimal mockup data set that illustrates what you want to do.

Comment: also, don't spend too much time trying convoluted `eval(paste(...` constructs in R; they're always an indication that there's a better approach for your problem.

Comment: The dataset is [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7pSZhKIbJhpdTB3dkJUdUY0ckk), and I'll work on making a mockup dataset.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723551/using-the-output-of-paste-as-an-object-within-a-for-loop-in-r?rq=1) looks like a similar question, but no answer, unfortunately.

Comment: See `[[` as a programmatic alternative to `$`. You can get to the help page by typing `?"[["`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with:

```
for(i in seq_along(groups)) {

  Results$Plot[i] <- groups[i] # character names of the groups
  tempZ = plotsgrouped[[groups[i]]][["Z"]]
  Results$Mean[i] <- mean(tempZ)
  Results$Std.Dev.[i] <- sd(tempZ)
  Results$Max[i] <- max(tempZ)
  Results$75%Avg.[i] <- mean(tempZ[tempZ <= quantile(tempZ, .75)])
  Results$50%Avg.[i] <- mean(tempZ[tempZ <= quantile(tempZ, .50)])

}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I had a feeling it had to do with brackets, but couldn't find an example of a 3-deep reference. +3 internets to you, sir!

Comment: All you needed to do was read ... very carefully ...  ?'[' ... it's all in the FM.

Comment: It never occurred to me that `[` would have its own help page. :-S